# How to send file/image in BlackBerry messenger using BBM PIN/Send to BBM Contact through BlackBerry Application

Tags: blackberry, sdk, share, bb-messenger

I want to share my app in `BlackBerry Messenger` from my Application.

I want to share my App icon and description of my Application. Is it possible to implement this without any `BBM Sdk` or any other way?

How to open `BBM Contact List` from the Application?

If anyone has an idea please suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to use the BBM Social Platform SDK to accomplish this.  The BBM Contact list isn't accessible in any case although with the SDK you can display it to the user, you won't be able to read the entire list.